# Does it have an issue if you install angular, reactjs, ionic, apache-cordova and karma in node js?

Tags: node.js, angular, reactjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Does it have an issue or conflicts if you install ionic and angular and then you install reactjs, apache-cordova and karma in npm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there would be no issues as long as you install them globally. just add -g every time you npm install something.

Answer (score 1):

If you install these packages *on the same project* you may have issues. All these frameworks are meant to work independent and you shouldn't use Angular if already using React or vice versa for instance.

If the packages are installed *on different projects*, then you are good to go. The package is only used by the project you installed it on (you can find all the packages installed for a project on the **node_modules** folder inside your project).

Comment: what if I installed it globally

Comment: like npm install -g ionic cordova and npm install -g babel

Comment: I believe that as long as you don't include them on your project's headers you shouldn't have issues, because the project will only use the packges you specify.

As from npm documentation, global installations are only for command line tools.
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally